# Remove Woocommerce cart quantity selector from cart page based on product ID

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I am trying to remove the quantity selector while leaving the item count to display in cart based on product ID. I have used the code kindly provided by 2 members. Unfortunately I am failing to splice it together without generating critical errors in WP.

to **remove the selector** I used the code from **Reigel Gallarde**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'wc_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
function wc_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ){
    if( is_cart() ){
        $product_quantity = sprintf( '%2$s <input type="hidden" name="cart[%1$s][qty]" value="%2$s" />', $cart_item_key, $cart_item['quantity'] );
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}
```

to use the specific **product ID** I used the code from **LoicTheAztec**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'hide_quantity_input_field', 20, 2 );
function hide_quantity_input_field( $args, $product ) {
    // Here set your product IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array(37,40,70);

    // Handling product variation
    $the_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // Only on cart page for a specific product category
    if( is_cart() && in_array( $the_id, $product_ids ) ){
        $input_value = $args['input_value'];
        $args['min_value'] = $args['max_value'] = $input_value;
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Both snippets work as intended separately and the code is right.
Problem is when I combine them. I am clearly doing something wrong though I do not think it's due to missing colon, I am probably calling wrong thing somewhere.
This is the code that I have that is not working for some reason..

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'hide_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
function hide_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item, $product ){
    // Here set your product IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array(117295,117343,99999999);
   
    // Handling product variation
    $the_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // Only on cart page for a specific product category
    if( is_cart() && in_array( $the_id, $product_ids ) ){
        $product_quantity = sprintf( '%2$s <input type="hidden" name="cart[%1$s][qty]" value="%2$s" />', $cart_item_key, $cart_item['quantity'] );
    }
    return $product_quantity;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the product ID from the cart key first

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'hide_cart_item_quantity', 10, 3 );
function hide_cart_item_quantity( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item){
    // Here set your product IDs in the array
    $product_ids = array(117295,117343,99999999);

    $cart_item = WC()->cart->get_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
    $product = wc_get_product($cart_item['product_id']);
    // Handling product variation
    $the_id = $product->is_type('variation') ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();

    // Only on cart page for a specific product category
    if( is_cart() && in_array( $the_id, $product_ids ) ){
        $product_quantity = sprintf( '%2$s <input type="hidden" name="cart[%1$s][qty]" value="%2$s" />', $cart_item_key, $cart_item['quantity'] );
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}
```